# Is mongodb a no-go for this application?

Tags: mongodb

Good sirs.
I've just started planning a new project, and it seems that I should stick with a relational database, (even though I want to play with mongo). Tell me if I'm mistaken!

There will be box models, each of which can contain hundreds to thousands of items.

At any time, the user can move an item to another box.
for example, using some Railsy pseudocode...

```
item = Item(5676)
item.box // returns 24
item.update(box:25)
item.box // returns 25
```

This sounds like a simple SQL join table to me, but an expensive array manipulation operation for mongodb.

Or is removing an object out of one (huge) array and inserting it in another (huge) array not a big problem for mongo?

Thanks for any wisdom. I've only just started with mongo.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you provide an example of the SQL syntax that you would use and then we can tell you the equivalent in Mongo?

Comment: if i were to do some extensive `join` stuff, i would prefer relational dbs, well but that's only my personal opinion

Comment: I'd just like to add that it might not be necessary to store everything into arrays. You wouldn't do that in SQL either.

Comment: Have a look at this ppt before to decide which one to use - SQL or NoSQL. http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/nosql-databases-why-what-and-when?qid=729d9acb-b3a8-42fa-9a75-1b48bbb24a0e&v=default&b=&from_search=1. Later decide on which NoSQL to use depending of CAP theory. Select 2 out Consistency, Availability & Partitioning

Comment: For Pros of MongoDB, visit this link : http://www.netsolutionsindia.com/blog/what-is-mongodb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use big arrays, stay away from MongoDB. I tell from personal experience. There are two big problems with arrays. If they start to grow, document grows and it needs to be moved on disk. That is very, very slow operation. Plus if you need to scan array to get to 10000 element, that will be very slow as it needs to check 9999 before that.

Comment: Okay. I've heard enough. No mongo for this one. Thanks!